# Why is ConsumerWidget not rebuilding when "watched" StateProvider's state changes?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

Hey yall I'm trying to figure out how Riverpod works but somehow I didn't even got the basic idea.

When i change `themeMode` `App` doesn't get rebuild even though it "watches" the associated `Provider`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

final themeModeProvider = StateProvider<ThemeMode>((ref) => themeMode);
var themeMode = ThemeMode.system;

void main() => runApp(const ProviderScope(child: App()));

class App extends ConsumerWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return MaterialApp(
      themeMode: ref.watch(themeModeProvider),
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                themeMode = ThemeMode.light;
              },
              child: const Text('light'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                themeMode = ThemeMode.dark;
              },
              child: const Text('dark'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

As far as I thought I understood, when accessing a value any `Provider` provides in a `ConsumerWidget` using `ref.watch()`, the widgets rebuilds whenever that value changes, but that doesn't seem to be the case.
I'd be so grateful if someone could explain to me how that stuff actually works cause everything I find online is not really beginners friendly and I thought Riverpod was supposed to make things easier.

Comment: The literature is rushing to catch up with Remi's prolific development.  In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).

Comment: Thanks a lot for pushing me into the right direction. Saved me a few hours of unnecessary studying

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `themeMode` to `themeModeProvider` only as the initial state. From now on, you have to update the state of the provider in this way:

```dart
ref.read(themeModeProvider.notifier).state = ThemeMode.light;
```

More on watching and reading `StateProvider`: https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/state_provider

Comment: I could swear I tried that. But works just fine. Thank you so much!!